# Приложение с регистрацией через ВК не работает на реальном устройстве

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Приложение при тестировании на эмуляторе работает исправно, однако при попытке тестировать на реальном устройстве, после нажатия на кнопку "вход через ВК", появляется следующая ошибка: **{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"sdk_package is incorrect"}**.
В настройках приложения на странице "ВК" в поле "название пакета для android" указан applicationId, MainActivity и сертификат тоже указаны верно. Помоги разобраться в чем проблема! Заранее спасибо!
Вот файл манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name=".app.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKOpenAuthActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoadActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Authorization"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity"
        android:label="ServiceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FriendsActivity"
        android:label="Друзья"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.GameActivity"
        android:label="Игра"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WaitingAnswerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_waiting_answer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ShowPopUp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AnswerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_answer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.showActiveGame"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_active_game" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.TempResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_temp_result" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_result" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Вот настройки приложения ВК:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/issues/10

Comment: Смотрел эту ссылку. Дело в том что все настройки приложения у меня корректные.

Comment: Покажите манифест

Comment: Исправил тему, добавил манифест и страничку с настройками приложения VK

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Comment: См. https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/issues/10. Нужно правильно прописать "Название пакета для Android", взять его из build.gradle и проверить, что для debug или release выставляете верно (может меняться).